# I've included a header file but I still get undefined when trying to run make

Tags: c

I am trying to implement bcrypt into an open source project I've found, more of a learning thing. I've git cloned https://github.com/rg3/bcrypt and moved the `bcrypt.h bcrypt.c` and `crypto_blowfish` into my projects file, then in my file `database.c` I've

```
include "bcrypt.h"
```

Then when I run `make` I get:

> database.c:2084: undefined reference to `bcrypt_checkpw'

This is how I'm using it

```
    int ret;
    ret = bcrypt_checkpw(pass, row[0]);
    assert(ret != -1);

    if (ret == 0) {
            return 1;
    } else {
            return 2;
    }
```

I have a `Makefile` I'm not sure if I did this right but I added `bcrypt.h` to the makefile

```
.obj/database.o:        database.c bcrypt.h server.h log.h create.h player.h sleep.h tool.h drdata.h drvlib.h timer.h direction.h map.h mem.h database.h misc_ppd.h badip.h
```

All compile

```
gcc -O -g -m32 -rdynamic -L/usr/lib/mysql -o server .obj/server.o .obj/io.o .obj/libload.o .obj/tool.o .obj/sleep.o .obj/log.o .obj/create.o .obj/notify.o .obj/skill.o .obj/do.o .obj/act.o .obj/player.o .obj/rdtsc.o .obj/los.o .obj/light.o .obj/map.o .obj/path.o .obj/error.o .obj/talk.o .obj/drdata.o .obj/death.o .obj/database.o .obj/see.o .obj/drvlib.o .obj/timer.o .obj/expire.o .obj/effect.o .obj/command.o .obj/date.o .obj/container.o .obj/store.o .obj/mem.o .obj/sector.o .obj/chat.o .obj/statistics.o .obj/mail.o .obj/player_driver.o .obj/clan.o .obj/lookup.o .obj/area.o .obj/task.o .obj/punish.o .obj/depot.o .obj/prof.o .obj/motd.o .obj/ignore.o .obj/tell.o .obj/clanlog.o .obj/respawn.o .obj/poison.o .obj/swear.o .obj/lab.o .obj/consistency.o .obj/btrace.o .obj/club.o .obj/teufel_pk.o .obj/questlog.o .obj/badip.o -lmysqlclient -lm -lz -ldl -lpthread
.obj/database.o: In function `load_char_pwd':
/home/ec2-user/astonia3_server/database.c:2084: undefined reference to `bcrypt_checkpw'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [server] Error 1
```

Comment: Please show the complete compiler command line.

Comment: @Bort you mean the makefile? or?

Comment: That's a linker error - you need to link with the file or library that defines the function. (The header only contains a declaration of it.)

Comment: Why don't you build the bcrypt library using the supplied makefile and link with that?

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm fairly new to C I've ran make, and I moved the `bcrypt.o` file into `.obj/` folder which my other project seems to be using, I've went into the `Makefile` and added `.obj/bcrypt.o` to it, what else do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

The `bcrypt_checkpw` in .h file is put on `extern C`so it has **C linkage**

The `bcrypt_checkpw` in .c file has **C++ linkage**

They are different symbols so you will get linking error.